HNSW: Does Increasing the 'k' Value Affect the Order of Search Results?
I'm working with Hierarchical Navigable Small World (HNSW) graphs for approximate nearest neighbor search. I understand that the 'k' parameter controls the number of nearest neighbors to be retrieved during graph traversal. However, I'm not clear on how increasing 'k' affects the following:
Order of Results: Does a higher 'k' value change the order in which search results are returned? If so, how to handle it during pagination.
Accuracy: Does increasing 'k' generally lead to more accurate results, or is there a trade-off with efficiency?
Implementation Specifics: Are there any implementation-specific behaviors (e.g., in libraries like Faiss) that I should be aware of regarding 'k' and result ordering?
